# How to loop through unknown worksheet names in a workbook using the SpreadsheetLight Library

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, spreadsheetlight

I'm trying to loop through unknown worksheet names in a workbook using the SpreadsheetLight Library.

Using the `SLDocument sl = new SLDocument("ModifyExistingSpreadsheetOriginal.xlsx", "Sheet1")` statement in the examples only allows a string input for the worksheet.

Is there some way to refer to a worksheet index or do something similar to a `foreach string sh in Workbook.Sheets` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `GetWorksheetNames()` method that looks like it will do exactly what you want:

```
var sl = new SLDocument("ModifyExistingSpreadsheetOriginal.xlsx");

foreach (var name in sl.GetWorksheetNames())
{
    // do something with each worksheet name
}
```

From their docs:

> Get a list of names of existing worksheets currently in the spreadsheet, excluding chart sheets, macro sheets and dialog sheets.

Comment: Thanks Grant!  The method is called GetSheetNames() in the version i downloaded, but it should do the trick.